# Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse = " and ") : n < m

Tags: r, combinations, frequency, tapply, combn

I have a 185,686 rows data frame with 11 variables but I'm only interested in two: Order.ID and Product

Each line of the original data frame contains an unique combination of ID, product, quantity, adress, etc. From this df I created a new one that only have the ID and product of the purchases in which more than one product was bought.

So I'm trying to discover which products are often sold together. **I have already ensured that the original data frame doesn't have identical lines or empty lines** and everything looks fine, except R says product has 21 levels but two of them were mistakes, so the data frames have only 19 levels of products. But if a type `nlevels(venda.id$Product)` I get 21.

```
  Order.ID  Product
1 176560    Google Phone
2 176560    Wired Headphones
3 176574    Google Phone
4 176574    USB-C Charging Cable
5 176586    AAA Batteries (4-pack)
6 176586    Google Phone
7 176672    Lightning Charging Cable
8 176672    USB-C Charging Cable
9 176681    Apple Airpods Headphones
10 176681   ThinkPad Laptop
11 176689   Bose SoundSport Headphones
12 176689   AAA Batteries (4-pack)
13 176739   34in Ultrawide Monitor
14 176739   Google Phone
15 176774   Lightning Charging Cable
16 176774   USB-C Charging Cable
17 176781   iPhone
18 176781   Lightning Charging Cable
```

```
structure(list(Order.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("176560", 
"176574", "176586", "176672", "176681", "176689", "176739", "176774", 
"176781", "176797"), class = "factor"), Product = structure(c(5L, 
10L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("34in Ultrawide Monitor", "AAA Batteries (4-pack)", 
"Apple Airpods Headphones", "Bose SoundSport Headphones", "Google Phone", 
"iPhone", "Lightning Charging Cable", "ThinkPad Laptop", "USB-C Charging Cable", 
"Wired Headphones"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem appears when I try to get the top 2 combinations:

```
tail(sort(table(unlist(tapply(as.character(venda.id$Product), venda.id$Order.ID, FUN=function(x) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse=" and "))))), 2)

Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse = " and ") : n < m
```

That code should produce something like: (not shure what the answer is)

```
Lightning Charging Cable and iPhone Wired Headphones and USB-C Charging 
                x                                y
```

x and y are the frequencies calculated by table `table`

If i dont use `as.character` for the Product column i get a different error:

`Error in class(out) <- class(x0) : adding class "factor" to an invalid object`

I have tried alternative codes, but I get the same error.

It worked the first time I runned, but the results seemed wrong because the counts were low as 16 and the data has 14,128 lines. Now it doesn't run anymore.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

**Update:** I detected the error occurs on lines 783 and 784, there are 2 equal products associated to the same ID, althought that doesn't happen in the original data.

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xts_0.12.1        zoo_1.8-9         lubridate_1.7.10  viridis_0.5.1    
 [5] viridisLite_0.3.0 hrbrthemes_0.8.0  forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0    
 [9] purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.3       tibble_3.0.6     
[13] tidyverse_1.3.0   dygraphs_1.1.1.6  ggplot2_3.3.3     dplyr_1.0.5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lattice_0.20-41   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.27    
 [5] utf8_1.1.4        R6_2.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.2.1  
 [9] reprex_1.0.0      evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.5.0     
[13] gdtools_0.2.3     rlang_0.4.10      readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13  
[17] extrafontdb_1.0   rmarkdown_2.7     labeling_0.4.2    extrafont_0.17   
[21] htmlwidgets_1.5.3 munsell_0.5.0     tinytex_0.30      broom_0.7.5      
[25] compiler_4.0.4    modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.21         systemfonts_1.0.1
[29] pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.1.1 tidyselect_1.1.0  gridExtra_2.3    
[33] fansi_0.4.2       crayon_1.4.1      dbplyr_2.1.0      withr_2.4.1      
[37] grid_4.0.4        jsonlite_1.7.2    Rttf2pt1_1.3.8    gtable_0.3.0     
[41] lifecycle_1.0.0   DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1     
[45] cli_2.3.1         stringi_1.5.3     farver_2.1.0      fs_1.5.0         
[49] xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1    generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6      
[53] tools_4.0.4       glue_1.4.2        hms_1.0.0         yaml_2.2.1       
[57] colorspace_2.0-0  rvest_1.0.0       knitr_1.31        haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: Also, I tried running `venda.id= venda.id[sapply(venda.id, function(x) length(unique(x)) >1)]` but nothing changed

Comment: I don't get any such error using your code for the data that you have shared.

Comment: I dont´t get either, it happens when i try to run in all the data

Comment: You seem to have `library(stringr)` installed, so maybe this is a whitespace problem with your `Product` names? Try importing your data (if this isn't your default already) with the option `, stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and then run `str_trim()` on your `Product` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the class types of the original dataframe.

```
venda.id <- type.convert(venda.id, as.is = TRUE)
```

After doing this run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a problem when the code get to line 783, I can make it work by doing

```
test=venda.id[784:14034, ]

tail(sort(table(unlist(tapply(as.character(test$Product), test$Order.ID, FUN=function(x) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse=" and "))))),
           2)
```

It also works in if I do `test=venda.id[1:782, ]`

but it won't work if line 783 is in the middle of the interval, I guess this happens beacause lines 782 and 783 have the same product, but with different IDs but this also happens before in the data and no erros occurred

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `type_convert`

```
library(readr)
vend.id <- type_convert(venda.id)
```